# Is there any way to dynamically add new property to spring

Tags: spring

I need to add new properties to spring dynamically Eg.

```
<bean id="test" class="TestBean" >
        <property name="testProperty">

</bean>
```

now i need to add new property to my TestBean at runtime without changing the java code

So is there any way to achieve the same

```
<bean id="test" class="TestBean" >
        <property name="testProperty">
                <property name="testProperty1">

</bean>
```

Comment: try given link : http://java.dzone.com/articles/dynamic-property-management